# Eloquent query using join to retrieve pivot table and related data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

In my controller I have a query like this:

```
$userinfos = User::with('skills');
$userinfos->with('positions');
$userinfos=$userinfos->get();
```

And that works fine, in my view, I get the position name like this:

```
@forelse ($userinfos[0]->positions as $key=>$position)
    {{ $position->name}}
@empty
    No position listed
@endforelse
```

I have another like this to retrieve related company data:

```
$positions = \DB::table('positions')
->select(\DB::raw('position_user.id as id, positions.id as position_id, positions.name as position_name, companies.id as company_id, companies.name as company_name, position_user.user_id'))
->join('position_user','position_user.position_id','=','positions.id')
->join('companies','companies.id','=','position_user.company_id')
->join('users','users.id','=','position_user.user_id')
->where('position_user.user_id',$userid)
->get();
```

And that also works fine to get the positions and company name:

```
@forelse($positions as $key=>$position)
    {{$position->position_name}} @ {{$position->company_name}}
@empty
    No position listed
@endforelse
```

I am sure there must be a way to combine the two so that I can get the company name in the first query. I am looking for something like this:

```
$userinfos = User::with('skills');
$userinfos->with('positions');
$userinfos->whereHas('positions', function($thisQuery) 
{
    $thisQuery->join('companies','companies.id','=','position_user.company_id');
});

$userinfos=$userinfos->get();
```

Is that even possible? Any ideas/direction would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

Should I perhaps be looking at adding in a join to my Position class to enable the above:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->withTimestamps()
    ->withPivot('company_id');
    ->join('companies','companies.id','=','position_user.company_id');
}
```

If so - how would I access that in the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably create your own pivot model such as UserPosition, and override the newPivot() method.

```
class User extends Eloquent {

public function positions() { 
   return $this->belongsToMany('Position')->withPivot('company_id');
}

public function newPivot(Model $parent, array $attributes, $table, $exists) {

if ($parent instanceof Position) {
    return new UserPosition($parent, $attributes, $table, $exists);
}

    return parent::newPivot($parent, $attributes, $table, $exists);
}

}
```

And you'd have the pivot model such as

```
class UserPosition extends  Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot { 

    public function company() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Company');
    }
}
```

Then you can do something like the code below. Of course you could iterate  positions instead of fetching first().

```
$user = User::find(1);
$user->positions()->first()->pivot->company
```

Please keep in mind I just wrote these as a guideline. Didn't test any of it. Hopefully you can apply the logic.

Comment: Thanks - will give that a go!

Comment: Although I didn't use this exactly as is, it pushed me in a different direction. I basically ended up restructuring my models so thanks for the help!